# aptana javascript code assistance (Some code assistances are missing)

Tags: php, javascript, html, aptana

I'm currently learning and playing around with javascript on Aptana 3 IDE. I love Aptana's code completion and template features of it but I'm having trouble with getting full code assistance for my javascript development. For instance, if I have a new Image instance like

```
var imgSprite = new Image();
```

and if I call it by saying imgSprite, it wouldn't suggest me code suggestion for like:

```
imgSprite.addEventListener('load', loadImage, false);
```

but it does suggest me code suggestions including `imgSprite.src`

So are there any extensions or plugin that I can install to get all those code assistance features working in my Aptana 3 IDE? or perhaps you can suggest me other IDE with all these features embedded? Thanks